# Field Validation in Admin when field are dependent on other fields

Tags: django-admin

How can i apply validation in admin on various fields when they are dependent on each other ?

e.g. Let say in i have a  Field A(BooleanField)  and Field B (CharField) what i want to do is if in admin user select the Field A(checkbox) and does not enter anything in Field B
and if he tries to save ,it should throw an error like a normal blank=False gives. So how can i do this kind of validation in admin .

E.g  Use Case

I have a table having the following structure :-

INTERVIEW_TYPES = (

```
    ('default', 'None'),
    ('Paired Visit','Paired Visit'),
    ('Time Series', 'Time Series'),

),
```

class Interview(models.Model):

```
ic_number              = models.CharField(verbose_name ="Visit Configuration Number",max_length=20,unique=True,null =True,blank=True)
ic_description         = models.TextField(verbose_name ="Visit Configuration Description",null = True,blank=True)
title                  = models.CharField(verbose_name ="Visit Configuration Title",max_length=80,unique=True)
starting_section       = models.ForeignKey(Section)
interview_type         = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Mapped Visit",choices=CHOICES.INTERVIEW_TYPES, max_length=80, default="Time Series")
select_rating          = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES.QUESTION_RATING, max_length=80, default="Select Rating")
view_notes             = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES.VIEW_NOTES, max_length=80, default="Display Notes")
 revisit                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

.....and so on ......

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Visit Configuration'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Visit Configurations'
   # ordering = ('rpn_number',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Its admin.py

class InterviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_display = ('id','title', 'starting_section','ic_number','show_prior_responses')
raw_id_fields = ('starting_section',)
```

admin.site.register(Interview, InterviewAdmin)

In admin , If i select the checkbox of revisit and in the field interview_type(which will show a dropdown having choices None,Paired Visit , Time Series) if a User has selected None from that dropdown and then press save button it should throw me an error like a normal blank=False shows, saying "This field is required"

How can i do this kind validation where fields are dependent on each other ?

Please Ignore syntax error is any .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got confused in response_change and overriding clean method finally this is what i did

## override clean method by making a model form in `admin.py`

```py
class  InterviewAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Interview

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(InterviewAdminForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.cleaned_data['interview_type'] == "default" \
        and self.cleaned_data['Revisit'] == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError({'interview_type': ["error message",]})
        return cleaned_data


class InterviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # call the form for Validation
    form = InterviewAdminForm
    #....and so on ....
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me that how can i display the error message just above that field for which validation is applied.Currently is is displaying the error message on top of the admin page. I want to show just above that field. In this case it should be above interview_type field like default admin shows "This field is required" just above that field. Thanks in advance